# Abrir arquivo de Input File com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um formulário apenas com um `input` do tipo `file` e um botão `submit`.

Quero pegar o conteúdo desse arquivo `txt` e salvar em uma variável, isso sem dar *refresh* e sem fazer *upload* do arquivo antes, tudo com JavaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso usando o **FileReader API**. No exemplo abaixo, você pode salvar o conteúdo do arquivo TXT selecionado no `input type=file` na variável `texto`:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" />

<script>
function lerArquivoTxt(evt){
    var texto = "";
    var files = evt.target.files;
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event){
            var conteudo = event.target.result;
            var linhas = conteudo.split('\n');
            for(x=0;x<linhas.length;x++){
               texto += linhas[x];
            }
            alert(texto);
        };
        reader.readAsText(f);
    }
}
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', lerArquivoTxt, false);
</script>
```